# Azure Resource Manager Template parameters

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am trying my hands on over Azure Resource manager templates.

So for making any new resource I am trying to find out which all parameters are required and if they are mandatory or optional. But couldn't get any documentation for same.

I am looking for documentation which is somewhat similar to AWS. To get better in sites about the resources.

Thanks in advance!!

**EDIT**
I am not looking for parameters in general which are passed to the template. What I want is the resources parameters. The parameters which are given under the **properties** tag of every resource

Example- 
In the below resource "virtualNetworks" there are resource parameters like *addressSpace*, *subnets*.
[virtualNetworks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6IF5.png)

Comment: Are you using existing templates or designing new templates from scratch?

Comment: Trying to create templates from scratch as per specific usecases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#) should help you.

It is the schema for deployment templates. Within it, there are schemas for every type of resource that can be put into an arm template. For example, if we look at the schema for [Virtual Machines](http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-08-01/Microsoft.Compute.json#/resourceDefinitions/virtualMachines), it contains all the available properties, profiles, extensions, what is required or not, etc.

However, it shouldn't be necessary for you to really look at this and learn it. When you are creating your arm template in visual studio, intellisense should kick in and show you whether what you are putting in the template is valid or not. For example, here I am editing the properties of a public IP, and it shows me what the available properties to add are.

[image: arm template intellisense]

Comment: Hey Ed thanks for your reply. The schema link that you have given is very helpful. However referring to *virtualNetworks* schema I can see **required** tag under each property of **definitions**. But cannot trace any **required** tag for  **definitions** which will state which properties under definitions are required. Any idea how can I get those as well?

Also, whenever I create a resource in visual studio. There are default parameters that it pops up for that particular resource. Should I assume those are the required parameters?

Answer (score 0):

you are right, there is a lack of documentation for resources and required parameters.

My advice is:

1. Check the Azure-Quickstart Templates, more than enough examples: [Quickstart Templates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates)
2. Since some days you can export ARM Templates from the Azure Portal. So create your resource in portal and export the Templates & Parameters: [Microsoft Blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/export-template/)
3. Check the resource Explorer: [Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will have to explore the 2nd option you mentioned. But the other options are kind of hard way out. It would have been easy if there was some proper documentation though.